# MYSQL to other DB migration using MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-workbench

is it possible to migrate MYSQL to other database platform like MS SQL 2012 using the MYSQL workbench migration wizard?. Everywhere the only destination DB is MYSQL, the reverse process is not explained at all.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench is primarily a tool to work with the MySQL database server and hence all implemented migrations ultimatively use MySQL as target. No other target is supported.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) doesn't have that capability. However, migrating away from MySQL is probably one of the easiest RDBMSs migrations possible.

Migrating data is easy- just export in CSV format and import to the desired target, or use ODBC as a compatibility layer. The complicated thing is something common to any migration- porting the schema, server-side programming (triggers, stored procedures, etc.) and changing your application to adopt a new database engine (which usually means using different query strategies, aside from syntax changes).  There are also hybrid tools like

Check the [Microsoft SQL Migration Assistant for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43688), but I have no previous experience with it.

Comment: thanks, i know SSMA but wanted to know about any possibility of MYSQL workbench